# Can DataFrame.apply reference previous rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that similar versions of this question have been asked, and I've seen answers of no, or else look at rolling_apply, but so far have not seen how I can implement a faster version of this code, although it seems it should be possible.

In a dataframe, I want to create a column, whose values are either equal to another column, or equal to its previous value (earlier row) depending on a second column.  I can do this in a loop but it is slow.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],'t':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

startTime = df.loc[0,'t']
df.loc[:,'startTime'] = startTime

for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[idx,'a'] == 0:
        startTime = df.loc[idx,'t']
    df.loc[idx,'startTime'] = startTime

df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
df['startTime'] = df.loc[df['a']==0, 't'].reindex(df.index).ffill()

df
Out: 
   a  t  startTime
0  0  0        0.0
1  1  1        0.0
2  2  2        0.0
3  0  3        3.0
4  1  4        3.0
5  2  5        3.0
6  0  6        6.0
7  1  7        6.0
8  2  8        6.0
```

Comment: Too quick for me +1

Comment: Perfect! That works well for me, in using this code on my actual code and not the demo, I found one recommendation to make this more general would be to reindex to df.index.  Thank you

Comment: @PaulFleming Ah yes that was a mistake just happened to work because `df['t']` and `df.index` are the same. I thought I passed `df['t']`'s index. Edited now, thanks.